# Using Selenium and GeckoDriver to load Firefox profile and recognize logins

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

So I was working on a bot with Python, Selenium, and GeckoDriver, but each time I would log in to a site the website would indicate that a new device has logged into my account. To prevent this I am looking to load a Firefox profile so that it will recognize me. I have scourged through quite a bit of stack overflow questions (many are outdated) as well as looked through the documentation, although I find it a little confusing to understand.

The problem is with the "add_argument": it simply opens the directory of the folder in the browser, instead of actually loading it.
[image]
A sample of the code where I am trying to open a profile:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import random
import time
import getpass
import sys

class TestBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        #Replace these lines
        #https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases --> Scroll to Assets and download appropriate file.   [For chrome, use ChromeDriver]
        new_driver_path = 'geckodriver-v0.33.0-win32/geckodriver.exe'
        #Location of your firefox browser.
        new_binary_path = r'C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'

        ops = options()
        ops.add_argument(r"C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\a2bk0f2m.default-release")
        ops.binary_location = new_binary_path
        serv = Service(new_driver_path)
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, options=ops)

#Deploy
username = "Test"
pwd = "test"
test = TestBot(username, pwd)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I needed to add the following line:

```
ops.add_argument("-profile")
```

I had to run the program a couple of times, but it actually did remember my login afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for returning with your findings. This helped me tremendously! Can confirm that adding this argument also allowed my script to pull the Firefox profile specified.